# Opening folder with spaces in folder name using opendir (adding quotes not working)

Tags: php, file-io, directory

Below is the simplified code I am using to open a folder which has spaces in the folder name.

```
$path = ABSOLUTE_MEDIA_PATH."training/".$cfolder['folder']."/".$coursename."/";
$directory = opendir("$path");


while(false!==$file=readdir($directory)) {

echo $file;
}
```

As you can see I have added the quotes to the folder path but it still isnt working. Below is the error Im getting

```
Warning: opendir(C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi1/media/training/profeuse/National Values and Principles of Governance/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdi1\components\students\courses\showcoursedocs.php on line 12

Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdi1\components\students\courses\showcoursedocs.php on line 16
```

Comment: have you tried removing the space from your folder and then try this solution to see if the problem is space at all!

Comment: "National Values and Principles of Governance" folder doesn't exist in path check that

Comment: Have you tried working with the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of using (forward) slashes on a Windows system?